# Cannot create function char using Graphics c#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, system.drawing

I'm trying to plot the function y = x ^ 2 at a certain interval using the Graphics, but I can't. When I write start + = 1/10 (to increase the number of points) knocks out the error that the index went beyond the array, and in this case what it is now, the graph does not look as it should. Maybe someone can help me build this chart using Graphics.
P.S: yes I know I can use Chart, but the task is to do it through Graphics.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace FormsForProgrammin
{
    public partial class Form15 : Form
    {
        PointF[] p = new PointF[10];
        int count = 0;
        public Form15()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form15_Paint);
            Calc();
        }
        private void Calc()
        {
            float start = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            while(start<= float.Parse(textBox2.Text))
            {
                float res = start * start;
                p[count] = new PointF(start, res);
                count += 1;
                start += 1;
            }
        }

        private void Form15_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(150, 150);
            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1, 0.25F);
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Blue, p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use an array, use a `List<PointF>`. When you call `Calc()` with new values (pass the values coming from the TextBox Controls, already validated using `float.TryParse()`, to the method), you reset the List. Or, handle multiple `List<PointF>`, to add to, e.g., a `Dictionary<int, List<PointF>>`, so you can choose to reset just one of the lists in the Dictionary, or all of them, or add new Lists.

Answer (score 1):

you have an array of 10 points, and you are indexing them with the count variable. you have a couple of problems in that code:

1. you never reset count
2. you set start to the textBox1 value, and increment it by 1 untill it is over the textBox2 value. but this gap may be bigger than the number of points you have in the array

to solve for 1 you can either reset count once the loop is done, or simply define count in the Calc method itself (the latter would be the better option, since count is only relevant to the Calc method)

to solve for 2 you would need to calculate a step amount: the difference between values divided by the number of points,
use this step amount to make sure that the loop doesn't run more times than the numbers of points you have